What is the standing of Russia and China regarding Israel's imminent attack on Iran?
On October 1, Iran carried out a significant ballistic and hypersonic missile attack on Israel some of which evaded the air defense systems and hit their targets. Since then, Israel has been threatening strong retaliation and at the time of writing, news are that this retaliation is imminent.
Did Russia or China (or both) make any statements indicating support for Iran in the face of Israeli threats?

Probably something along the lines of eats popcorn

Officially Russia has only stated that the situation is "developing to alarming scenario" and that they "condemn any actions resulting in civilian casualties".
Russian gov't benefits from higher oil prices which instability in the middle east brings. However, Russia doesn't want Iran to be engaged in broader war because it relies on Iran's military aid for its war in Ukraine such as ballistic missiles which in a war vs. Israel the Iranian capability to assist Russia decreases.
Also Russian troops are deployed in propping up the Assad regime in Syria, which also depends not only on Russian but also on Iranian military aid. Any serious blow to Iranian military or geopolitical capacity will weaken Assad's regime and require Russia to funnel more resources there, which it currently needs to fight Ukraine.

That was Peskov saying that BTW, on Oct 2. There were later statements by Ryabkov, but I guess he's somewhat lower in the pecking order over there. Alt translation https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/kremlin-calls-restraint-middle-east-after-iranian-attack-israel-2024-10-02/

Do you have references for these quotations? The phrasing in the links in comments is different.

@ToivoSäwén https://www.rbc.ru/politics/01/10/2024/66fc2a609a79477dfca6d07d — bullet point about Peskovs/Kremlin comments

Oh, the irony: Russia relying on Iran.

Kind of. If we believe Iranian media:

3 Oct 2024
In a statement to Sputnik on Thursday, Russian Deputy Foreign Minister Sergey Ryabkov emphasized that considering such scenarios is unacceptable.
He expressed deep concern, highlighting that any escalation of the current war could lead to severe consequences.
"I also want to say that nuclear facilities as such, in any case, should always be take out of any conflict," Ryabkov stressed.

Found the actual Sputnik piece. Only the first half of it is about Iran; the rest is about BRICS.
OTOH Tass, in English at least, seems to have chosen to select a much briefer passage:

3 Oct 2024
"We are in the closest contact with Iran on the current situation," he noted.
"We share a wonderful experience of cooperation in various fields. I think this is the moment when our relations are particularly important," the senior diplomat stressed.

That's followed by a context para on IRGC's missile attack from Oct 1. (You might not have guessed just from what they quoted from him.)
I'm not sure how much stock to put on this, but the NYT cites unnamed Iranian officials requesting advance warning of the attack from Moscow's satellites. Alas, the Russian response is not recorded. I also recall reading about the 2020 Iranian missile attack on the US bases in Iraq that they didn't have such help then, and had to rely on commercial sat images, a fact that the US was able to exploit to move their assets knowing when the commercial sats take their images that Iran would be able to buy. Western press reports in August were that Iran also intensified their attempts to strike a satellite intelligence purchase/contract with Chinese companies, but that nothing had been inked yet. Iran does have their own imaging sat launched by a Russian rocket in 2022; the sat itself was reportedly built by two Russian companies, to Iranian specs. The also have a couple domestically built and launched sats of lower resolution, but I guess the more intel, the better.
Also, Iran has long been requesting Su-35s jets and S-400 SAMs (they've got some S-300) from Russia, which would probably help somewhat, but it's unclear if Moscow will deliver those in time for this round of strikes.

I'm not sure if this is the latest word from China, as the article/statement is from Oct 2, but while it warns against escalation in Lebanon, and notes the ballistic missile attack too (in the 3rd para), it seems to say nothing about the potential Israeli retaliation against Iran itself. And it's a pretty long article that starts by paraphrasing from their Foreign Ministry. Somewhere towards the middle of it, they quote some Chinese academic who berates the free hand the US is giving Israel to take "unrestricted military action".
There was also a statement at the UN by the Chinese rep, published on Oct 3. It again focuses on Lebanon, and doesn't seem to touch on a potential Israeli strike on Iran, explicitly. But there some general calls (somewhat similar to how China approaches the war in Ukraine, at the declarative level) that

every effort must be made to prevent the spread of the fighting; and the parties concerned must return to the track of political and diplomatic solutions. [...] China urges all parties, especially Israel, to exercise restraint and avoid any actions that could further escalate the situation.
[...] Warning that the current situation is "hanging by a thread," Fu said any procrastination would be irresponsible, and any rhetoric of condoning further military adventurism would send a wrong message and could cause serious consequences.


In meantime Lavrov and Ryabkov have both warned Israel against striking Iran's nuclear facilities. But they've not said what Russia would do should Israel not heed that warning.

Very interesting. But, please, avoid abbreviations such as "para",  "sat intel" that I understood at first as sat(ellite) Intel (the electronics firm) before understanding you were meaning Intel(ligence).

That quote about nuclear facilities is a bit rich coming from Russia, given the fighting around Zaporizhzhia early in the Ukraine war.

@MichaelSeifert: sure, it's not like they're not also famous for saying negotiations are pointless, while calling for immediate ceasefires elsewhere.

The Iranians have been spreading the fake news that Putin has publicly promised them full military support if the US supports an attack on Iran. Nevertheless, it does appear that if Israel does launch a full-scale attack on Iran, Russia will likely be dragged into the middle-east conflict as their standing has changed with Iran in recent times.
Russia's foreign policy with the regional powers in the middle-east, so far, has been to use a hands-off approach to not upset any of them. But the Ukraine war and the western sanctions has recently forced a tilt in favour of Iran:

Jewish News Syndicate: Iran has reportedly provided Russia with around 400 surface-to-surface ballistic missiles, including models from the Fateh-110 family, which are crucial for Russia’s operational capabilities. Additionally, Iran has supplied thousands of drones, notably the Shahed-136, which have been used extensively in Ukraine. Iran’s support for Russia extends to significant production assistance. The Islamic Republic has helped establish a production factory on Russian soil dedicated to manufacturing 10,000 Iranian-designed drones a year, according to a February report by Defense One.


The Christian Science Monitor: Trade between Russia and Iran has expanded rapidly in the past few years, in a wide range of goods beyond energy cooperation and weaponry. One big item is Russia’s investment of almost $700 million in an Iranian railway that will complete the last section of the North-South Corridor, a long-discussed and much-delayed transport route that would connect Iranian ports on the Indian Ocean with Russia’s vast railway network. The completed line would help defeat efforts to sanction Russia and could potentially rival the Suez Canal as a trade route.

After Israel attacked Iran, Iran has been requesting defensive and offensive weapons from Russia in preparation for an imminent attack from Israel. While Russia has advised restraint, it has apparently also obliged them - the Israelis believe that Russia has started joint research and development in drone warfare with Iran and has started providing Iran with air defence equipments and radars:

The Jerusalem Post: Recently, Moscow and Tehran began working together on new types of unmanned aerial vehicles, or drones, according to intelligence sources and leaked documents ... Versions of the jet-powered drone, dubbed the MS-237, Shahed-238 and Shahed-236, have been described as having a top speed of around 400km/h - about three times that of previous models of Iranian drones. Tehran revealed the existence of the new drone at an air show in November. At the demonstration, the jet drone - codenamed "motorboat" in Russian internal communications - "successfully took off, performed the missions... and landed successfully by parachute," according to a leaked Russian report. "Given its high speed, the 'motorboat' is actually a cruise missile."


The New York Times: Two Iranian officials familiar with the war planning, one a member of the Revolutionary Guards Corps, confirmed that Iran has made the request and said Russia has started delivering advanced radars and air-defense equipment. The officials spoke on the condition of anonymity because they were not authorized to discuss the aid publicly.


Carnegie Politika: Judging by official statements, Moscow has agreed to supply Tehran with military helicopters and fighter jets: Su-35 fighters, Mi-28 attack helicopters, and Yak-130 jet trainers. Some of the latter have already been delivered, and Iranian pilots are using them for training purposes. Su-35s could be delivered as early as this year.

Iran is all set to negotiate and sign a new military and strategic agreement with Russia in mid-October 2024. This Israeli analysis - Will Russia Support Iran If It Conducts a Full-Scale Attack on Israel? - suggests that, barring any misstep from Israel and the US, Russian and Iranian relationship will likely remain transactional and is unlikely to transform into a fully strategic partnership because of the differing political values they have.
China already has a history of working with Iran, and it was China and North Korea that helped Iran develop its missile program. According to the Stockholm International Peace Research Institute, China was among the top three arms transfer partners for Iran. Iran is also one of the top 6 sources of oil for China. So it is very likely to follow the Russian approach of strengthening Iranian military to ensure that it isn't weakened in any manner by an Israeli or US-Israeli attack on Iran.
References:

Putin didn't pledge Russian support for Iran if US retaliates for attack on Israel | Fact check
Russia Is Being Drawn Deeper Into the Middle East Conflict
As Iran attack looms, competing US, Russian roles surface
Russia tried to stay on good terms with Iran and Israel. Then they started fighting.
Russian aid to Iran: what deals are being made in dangerous partnership?
Russian emissary visits Tehran at a tense moment as Iran asks for military aid.
Will Russia Support Iran If It Conducts a Full-Scale Attack on Israel?


That 1st bit was in April BTW. And I'm not entirely sure that self-styled "MAGA communist" Jackson Hinkle is an Iranian mouthpiece, but he's praised Assad and Putin before IIRC.

@IVFcomesfromthetip When it comes to Americans, you don't need to be anyone's mouthpiece to paint the picture that Russia is doing something detrimental to US interests - both the Democrats and the Republicans will use it in different propaganda to attack each other.

Well, you wrote "The Iranians have been spreading the fake news that Putin has publicly promised them full military support". But the only source doing that seems to have been that Hinkle guy, at least according to the story you linked. And even that piece doesn't use the term "fully military support", just "support", which is far more vague.

@IVFcomesfromthetip Yes, one of the sources I came across said Iranians are forwarding that particular fake news on Telegram, in Iran. (I didn't mean that the Americans created it for the Iranians - that's probably just a spill over side effect).

Weapon supply won't make Russia a part of this conflict.

@user13964273 Depends on the weapon and how well the Iranian military performs against Israel - if the weapons / Iran upsets the "balance of power" in the region, then the US may be forced to get involved to protect its ally. If the US gets directly involved, then that will drag Russia and China too. For e.g. US opposes Russia selling Su-35 to Iran.

@sfxedit According to Singh intercepting of missiles is a direct involvement and US took part in the interception of Iran's missiles so USA is already in this war.

@user13964273 Yes, the Anglo-Americans are supporting Israel at many levels. But even they don't want a war with Iran right now because it isn't a divided Lebanon or Syria with a weak military. While the US and Israeli media are pretending to brush-off the recent Iranian missile strikes against Israel, the only reason it didn't do any real harm (collateral damage) is because Russia pressured Iran to not target populated areas. As the Guardian reports, the Iranian missile attacks were in fact quite successful in penetrating Israel's Iron Dome and can be lethal.
